# Why is nobody dead?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

So I'm a short way into the game and I don't understand why everyone has been alive for centuries? It seems that the end of the world has been coming for 500 years and everyone it just still alive?

So, why is everyone still alive? What is stopping them from dying and why have they existed for centuries?

Comment: Assuming you've played FF13, you should know that their storytelling isn't the most straightforward. They'll explain everything as the game progresses ;)

Comment: The answer to this question would spoil the story.

Comment: The answer to the question in is FFXIII-2. It isn't a secret...

Comment: Agree with @Reafexus, FFXIII-2 should be played before LR.

Comment: Ah ok, it's been a long time since I finished 13-2

Comment: I would answer the question but I only know the result. I forget the justification for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading on Wikipedia about [the plot of FF 13-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII-2#Plot).

> ! Caius has been driven mad by watching her [Yuel] die repeatedly and seeks to end the process by unleashing the chaos trapped in Valhalla to destroy all time.
>
> ! [After Serah dies] Just then, a black cloud erupts from the sky as the chaos that Etro was keeping trapped breaks free.

So it seems that the Chaos has stopped the flow of time, which means that people no longer age, nor do they die. Hence why, in the final chapter of the story in FF Lightning Returns, everyone has been alive for centuries.

Comment: actually they can still die by anything except Old Age.  Only one lucky NPC got die by old age